# How to insert a json data into postgresql using database function cal without create entity model(getter and setter) in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-13

I am new to spring java. I have a controller class and repository class. what I actually want is to insert a json data into postgresql database by calling a database function(stored procedure)and return a json data as response.It shows that BAD SQL Grammar Error. Please help me to solve the issue...I am sharing my code. I am getting error in the
Map<String, Object> result =insertSurveyCall.execute(params); line.

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savedbData", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam String data,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException
 {
    
    JSONObject requestJSON= new JSONObject(data);
    String result="";
    result=userRepository.saveDatahouse(requestJSON);
    return result.toString();
  }

UserRepository.java
public interface UserRepository {   
String saveDatahouse( JSONObject requestJSON) throws SQLException;

}

 UserRepositoryImpl.java

@Override
public String saveDatahouse(JSONObject requestJSON) throws SQLException {
    JSONObject dbdata = requestJSON;
    JSONObject resultJSON = new JSONObject();
     Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     String reult="";
    try {
          PGobject pObj = new PGobject();
          pObj.setType("json");
          pObj.setValue(dbdata.toString());
              SimpleJdbcCall insertSurveyCall = new                 SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("add_data_to_db");
          params.put("params", pObj); 
          Map<String, Object> result =insertSurveyCall.execute(params); 
          System.out.println("result at repository::::::::::::::::::::::::");
          return resultJSON.toString(); 
         
    } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```